# IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a problem with my Visual web Developer when every time i use my Local IIS Web server i get this error IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility

but then i already installed my IIS 6 in my windows feature.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?  What OS is your server (and version)?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 , Win 7 Home Premium

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 has IIS clamped-down so tight that it is VERY difficult to use with Visual Studio.  For this reason, MS has given you 2 other recommended options: 1) use the debugging web server built into Visual Studio (pro).  2) Download and install IIS Express.

I know it seems like the IIS built-into Win7 should work better than IIS express, but IIS express is actually the same thing as the debugging web server built into VStudio Pro.  (also known as Cassini), but it has more management features, etc.

Nearly every developer that I know who has tried using the IIS built-into Win7, has given-up and chosen one of the two options I've mentioned.

For more information, developer.com has a nice article about IIS vs Cassini vs IIS Express.  http://www.developer.com/net/deciding-on-a-microsoft-web-server-cassini-iis-and-iis-express.html Or you can bing/goog the same topic.

Comment: -1: count me as an exception. I have never had any problems with IIS on a non server machine. In fact, the primary limitation I'm aware of is the limit to only one site.

Comment: @John Saunders, how about giving a better answer. Saying "it works for me" is not very helpful.  Especially when you comb through the list of similar questions (to the right) and notice that several of those have no good answers, or the existing answers don't work.

Comment: Your answer will work, but is not necessary. The built-in IIS works just fine. Also, without the actual error message, are you sure you know what the _problem_ is?

Comment: thnks for your replies i have already fix my problem regarding with my IIS by following the instructions listed in this website , http://forums.iis.net/p/1148581/1866381.aspx